# infopath: hide control if all choices are filtered away

Tags: infopath, infopath-2007

In infopath, I have a choice box that gives a choice of values from a secondary data source that is filtered.

How can I make the control hide if there is nothing matching the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you use the count function to set a field to the value of the count of the filter, then hide the control if that field reads 0.